# How to have multiple correct activations on one training example?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm trying to teach a tensorflow-keras neural network to play picross on a 5*5 grid. Ideally, the network would have 25 neurons on the output layer, each with a correct activation of 1 if that square is full, and 0 if it is empty.

So one training example's correct answer' activations would be a string of ones and 0s, 25 digits long. However, so far, I only know how to train a network to have one correct answer per training example.

I've trained a neural network to classify the MNIST handwritten digits.

I've already set up a way to generate the training data, including the picross grid and the relevant hints.

```
#x_train is a list of lists. Each sub_list contains the relevant hints for one particular training case

x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)

network = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu))
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu))
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
network.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
network.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Ideally, the output layer of the network will be 25 neurons, each activated or not. But currently, i get the error message:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 25

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely from **tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)**.
The `logits` argument expects class indices rather than one-hot encoded indices.

To have multiple binary outputs, you should instead minimise the binary cross entropy loss.

Replace:

```
network.compile(optimizer='adam',
     loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
     metrics=['accuracy'])
```

With:

```
network.compile(optimizer='adam',
     loss='binary_crossentropy',
     metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: In that case, how do you format the correct labels for the data, the y axis? Is it an array, a list, a list of arrays... Is it composed of integers, binary numbers...  How do you format the data?